# AngularJS Angular-dragdrop Nested issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

Having issues with a nested tree structure using the angular-dragdrop directive: https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop.  Was wondering if anyone has worked with this directive and have got it to work with nested structures.

Here is what I have:
HTML:

```
<span ng-if="rootFolder.expanded" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open hoverable" ng-click="rootFolder.expanded = false"></span>
<span ng-if="!rootFolder.expanded" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close hoverable" ng-click="myShoebox.expanded = true"></span>
<a class="hoverable" ng-click="openEntity(rootFolder)">{{rootFolder.title}}</a>
<ul class="file-system-list file-system-list-first" ng-show="rootFolder.expanded" ng-model='myShoebox.folders' jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'moveFolder(rootFolder)',index: {{$index}}}" data-drop="true">
    <li ng-repeat="folder in rootFolder.folders"data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="rootFolder.folders" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true, onStart:'dragFolder(folder)'}" ng-include="'file_system_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="file_system_renderer.html">
    <span ng-if="folder.expanded" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open hoverable" ng-click="folder.expanded = false"></span>
    <span ng-if="!folder.expanded" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close hoverable" ng-click="getChildren(folder)"></span>
    <a class="hoverable" ng-click="openEntity(folder)">{{folder.title}}</a>
    <ul class="file-system-list" ng-show="folder.expanded" data-drop="true" ng-model='folder.folders' jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'moveFolder(folder)',index: {{$index}}}">
        <li ng-repeat="folder in folder.folders" ng-show="folder.title" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="folder.folders" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true, onStart:'dragFolder(folder)'}" ng-include="'file_system_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Javscript:

```
$scope.rootFolder = {"folders":[{"title":"fake`enter code here`","folders":[]},{"title":"fake 2","folders":[]}]}
```

That rootFolder object has the ability to be infinitely nested.  I can't seem to drag and drop folders into other folders at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and found [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree). Although I eventually ended up writing my own, because I wanted to use the HTML5 drag & drop API: [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested)